# Does prostitution in Thailand make up around 10% of its GDP?

Tags: prostitution, thailand

There are several sources that make a claim like that, I'm giving some of them:

- [We don’t do sex work because we are poor, we do sex work to end our poverty](https://www.opendemocracy.net/en/beyond-trafficking-and-slavery/we-don-t-do-sex-work-because-we-are-poor-we-do-sex-work-to-end-our-poverty/)

  Key sentence in that link:

  > We are also the backbone of the tourism industry, which makes up around 10% of Thailand’s annual GDP.
- [Sex toys popular in Thailand despite conservative laws](https://thethaiger.com/thai-life/entertainment/sex-toys-popular-in-thailand-despite-conservative-laws)

  Key sentence in that link:

  > The sex industry is thought to comprise up to 10% of Thailand’s gross domestic product.
- [Sun, sea, sand... and a £5bn sex trade: Seedy side of Brit crooks' Thai haven where he fled to escape drugs charges before prostitute death quiz](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/sun-sea-sand-5bn-sex-11824796)

  Key sentence in that link:

  > It is a lucrative business, generating around £4.5billion a year – 10% of Thailand’s GDP.

I'm aware that Thailand is well known as a sex tourism country, but, even so, I find that for prostitution to make up 10% of its GDP it would be an extremely humongous phenomenon there.

Comment: Your first claim says that the _tourism industry_ is 10%, which may be more credible (though still exaggerated)

Comment: @pipe, I find the first claim to be ambiguous, not sure if "which" refers just to "tourism industry" or "the backbone of the tourism industry", anyway the other 2 claims make clear that 10% is just for the sex industry. Due to that, I think the first one also refers to 10% being generated by sex industry, but it has been written in an ambiguous way.

Comment: @pipe 10% seems too low; before the COVID-19 pandemic, [it was more in the order of 20%](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1143467/thailand-share-of-tourism-to-gdp/).

Comment: @gerrit the only statistic available on your link shows 65%, and [this page](https://www.theglobaleconomy.com/rankings/international_tourism_revenue_to_GDP/) shows about 3%.

Comment: @WeatherVane Hm?  I see a graph that shows 17.5% for three years, then (2020) it drops to ~5%.

Comment: @WeatherVane That page only covers *international* tourism.  The tourism industry in general and prostitution in particular also includes a domestic component.

Comment: EU countries aren't too skittish to try to estimate this https://www.imf.org/en/Data/Statistics/informal-economy-data/Reports/ECB-Estimation-of-prostitution-services-in-Europe-in-the-context-of-the-external-accounts but I think Thailand would be. So it's doubtful you'd get much better data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This difficult to estimate even in developed countries. Best I could find for East Asia, in general, is [this from the ILO](https://www.ilo.org/global/about-the-ilo/newsroom/news/WCMS_007994/lang--en/index.htm), from 1998 (duh!):

> The sex sector in the four countries [Indonesia, Malaysia, Philippines and Thailand] is estimated to account for anywhere from 2 to 14 per cent of Gross Domestic Product (GDP), and the revenues it generates are crucial to the livelihoods and earnings potential of millions of workers beyond the prostitutes themselves.
>
> [...] In Thailand, for example, close to US$300 million is transferred annually to rural families by women working in the sex sector in urban areas, a sum that in many cases exceeds the budgets of government-funded development programmes. For the 1993-95 period, the estimate was that prostitution yielded an annual income of between US$22.5 and 27 billion.

The GDP of Thailand [was](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.KD?locations=TH) about $200 billion back then (in 2015 dollars), so 10% doesn't seem outlandish. In  fact it was probably more, percentage wise, in 1995 dollars.

Another press article, also from 1999 [says](https://www.forbes.com/forbes/1999/0614/6312214s2.html?sh=f09b8a82cc7b)

> A study by a Thai university estimated the sex sector at around $25 billion, or 12% of the country's gross domestic product.

There are no other [relevant] details, but I suspect it's referring to the same dataset.

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostitution_in_Thailand)

> In 2015 Havocscope said that about US$6.4 billion in annual revenue was being generated by the trade, a figure which accounted for 10 percent of Thailand's GDP. Havocscope says that sex workers in Thailand send an annual average of US$300 million to family members who reside in more rural areas of Thailand.

So I suspect that's where the newer claims come from. The original article cited by Wikipedia doesn't load for me. And given that it's dropping the same US$300 figure as the much older ones, I suspect the actual data is the same, and probably just extrapolated i.e. carried forward.

Comment: FWTW, a newer study in South Korea (2013) puts the figure there at 1.66% of their GDP https://escholarship.org/uc/item/8wk7r6qz